# doubts about setters and getters

Tags: objective-c, getter-setter

I have a class, `Object2D`, with the following interface:

```
@class Point2D;
@class Vector2D;

@interface Object2D : NSObject
{
    Point2D* position;
    Vector2D* vector;
    ShapeType figure;
    CGSize size;
}

@property (assign) CGSize size;
@property ShapeType figure;

- (Point2D*) position;
- (void)setPosition:(Point2D *)pos;
- (Vector2D*) vector;
- (void)setVector:(Vector2D *)vec;
- (id)initWithPosition:(Point2D*)pos vector:(Vector2D*)vec;
- (void)move:(CGRect)bounds;
- (void)bounce:(CGFloat)boundryNormalAngle;
- (void)draw:(CGContextRef)context;

@end
```

And implementation:

```
@implementation Object2D

@synthesize size;
@synthesize figure;

- (Point2D*) position
{
    return position;
}
- (void)setPosition:(Point2D *)pos
{
    if (position != nil) {
        [position release];
    }
    position = pos;
}

- (Vector2D*) vector
{
    return vector;
}

- (void)setVector:(Vector2D *)vec
{
    if (vector != nil) {
        [vec release];
    }
    vector = vec;
}

...

- (void) dealloc
{
    if (position != nil) {
        [position release];
    }
    if (vector != nil) {
        [vector release];
    }
}
```

I don't use `@synthesize` with `position` and `vector` because I think, I have to release them before change their values.

I have two question:

If I want to get position value, **is this correct? Will I get a reference to position or a new one?**

```
ball = [[Object2D alloc] init];
ball.position = [[Point2D alloc] initWithX:0.0 Y:0.0];
ball.vector = [[Vector2D alloc] initWithX:5.0 Y:4.0];

Point2D* pos2;

pos2 = ball.position; <-- IS THIS CORRECT?
```

Second question:

**Do I need to release previous values before assign new ones to `position` and `vector`?**

Answer (score 3):

If you use...

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Point2D *position;
```

and the same for vector it will do the retain / release for you. (and @synthesize them obviously!)

So if you do the following....

```
Point2D *newPosition = [[Point2D alloc] init];
[myObject setPosition:newPosition];
[newPosition release];
```

OR

```
[myObject setPosition:[[[Point2D alloc] init] autorelease]];
```

Then the retains / releases will be handled. You will need to add a dealloc to your Object2D class and do EITHER....

```
[position release];
```

OR

```
[self setPosition:nil];
```

both will release the object upon cleanup.

Comment: So, if I use these I don't to do release on setter method, isn't it? Sorry, but I don't understand very well english.

Comment: If you use these, then you don't need to write ANY specific setter methods they will be created for you with the retain / release handled.

Comment: Ok, If I have an instance of Point2D in position, and I change position value, I'm not going to have a memory leak, isn't it?

Comment: I'll do something like `ball.position =[[Point2D alloc] init];`. If I use @synthesize, I don't need to use `[ball setPosition:newPosition];. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: ball.position is the same as [ball setPosition:  BUT in your example you will have a leak, you will need ball.position = [[[Point2D alloc] init] autorelease]; When you alloc / init the point, it has a retain count of 1, when you set that via ball.position = point it gets sent another retain, you need to release your retain so autorelease is the easiest way for you.

Comment: I'm so sorry, but I don't understand your answer. I've improved my question. I don't know why I need an autorelease with every Point2D that I assign to `position` field. I have a dealloc method to release `position` and `vector`. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an error on my code. Correct setters methods could be:

```
- (void)setPosition:(Point2D *)pos
{
    [pos retain];
    [position release];
    position = pos;
}

- (void)setVector:(Vector2D *)vec
{
    [vec retain];
    [vector release];
    vector = vec;
}
```